# DB connection is not closed after request ends in a NancyFx application

Tags: database-connection, nancy, tinyioc

I'm building a Nancy web app, and using OrmLite for DB access. I noticed that every request opens up a new DB connection and doesn't close it. I thought that registering the OrmLiteConnection class in the Application container would make it application-scoped, but it looks like I'm missing something.

Here's my code (in `ConfigureApplicationContainer`):

```
container.Register<OrmLiteConnectionFactory>(new OrmLiteConnectionFactory(connectionString, SqlServerDialect.Provider));
container.Register<OrmLiteConnection>(
            (cContainer, overloads) => (OrmLiteConnection) cContainer.Resolve<OrmLiteConnectionFactory>().Open());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I moved registration of `OrmLiteConnection` to `ConfigureRequestContainer`. Then I overrode `RequestStartup` and added:

```
pipelines.AfterRequest += (ctx) => {
    //close the connection
    container.Resolve<OrmLiteConnection>().Dispose();
};
```

Comment: Is this correct?  When I try this, it constructs a new instance (in my case, a DbContext), then disposes it right away.

Comment: I've registered it as a singleton in ConfigureRequestContainer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add [scope](https://github.com/grumpydev/TinyIoC/wiki/Registration---lifetimes#lifetimes) to your registration(s):

```
container
    .Register<OrmLiteConnectionFactory>(new OrmLiteConnectionFactory(connectionString, SqlServerDialect.Provider))
    .AsSingleton(); // I think this is by default, but sometimes being explicit is good.

container
    .Register<OrmLiteConnection>(
        (cContainer, overloads) => (OrmLiteConnection) cContainer.Resolve<OrmLiteConnectionFactory>().Open())
    .AsPerRequestSingleton();;
```

AFAIK, this will ensure the instances are disposed at the scope's end. Therefore, if you need to do more than `Dispose()` then you might need to find some way of supplying a delegate that can executed at that time.

Comment: The first line doesn't work -- says, Nancy.TinyIoc.TinyIoCRegistrationException: Cannot convert current registration of Nancy.TinyIoc.TinyIoCContainer+InstanceFactory to singleton

Comment: Turned out that factory methods are not compatible with Singleton lifecycle. A known TinyIoC limitation.

Comment: Ah. Good to know.